# C/C++ code from IntelliJ IDEA (just as editor, not compiler)

Tags: c++, c, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

Can I use IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3 for C/C++ code? I do not need to compile the code, just need to write it down (so to use IntelliJ as editor).

I need kind of a plugin or code inspection for C/C++, does exist something like this?

For a `.c` file, IntelliJ IDEA does not know how to indent the code. I think is a plugin but for older versions of IntelliJ IDEA. I use IntelliJ IDEA for Java, Python and now I need also for C; I don't want to install another IDE (CLion).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no official standalone plugin for C/C++ editing available for IntelliJ IDEA regardless of the version. You can vote up [this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4141) to change it.

The only third-party plugin that ever provided a set of editing features for `.c` files was ['C/C++'](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373-c-c-). It existed back in 2015, but is long dead now and not available for installing in the recent versions of IntelliJ IDEA to prevent app crashes.

You could try installing a [very old version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html) of the IDE like 2016 or something, and the [last available version](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373-c-c-/versions) of the abovementioned plugin. Could work, but no guarantees (and arguably not worth the hassle as outdated versions will have outdated bugs).